# Jquery, Targeting New Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

I am quite new to the realm of Javascript and the Jquery Library, so bear with me please.

I am manipulating the DOM by adding new divs within a parent div like so:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var addTst = document.getElementById("tst");
addTst.appendChild(newdiv)

 <div id ="tst">
 //new divs will appear here
 </div>

$("#tst  div").draggable(); *//things I need to be draggable*

#tst  div{
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:red;
margin:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

However I am attempting to use Jquery UI, to target these new elements and make them draggable. (The new divs are added by the user after the initial document loading, without refreshing the Jquery/page).
Of course Jquery only loads once so anything added after  remains undraggable.

I already have some AJAX in there, which is loading data fine, but it is quite long and I dont want to re-run the entire AJAX function just to refresh the  parent divs contents  (Assuming AJAX can update a div with new contents).

To help illustrate I have added a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YuGhj/2/

As you can see, the first red box drags fine, but if you add a new child using the button, they are not draggable.

I am most likely totally misunderstanding how jquery/AJAX works.

TL;DR
To put it shortly, I need a way to target elements added dynamically after the first page load, and apply a drag function to them. I assume I need to refresh the div somehow, without losing any contents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating the DOM is much easier with jQuery. Here's code to create a div, append it, and call `draggable` on it:

```
$('<div/>').appendTo('#tst').draggable();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MvXR3/

A lot of people seem to misunderstand how selecting and binding work. When you do this:

```
$("#tst  div").draggable();
```

That finds all elements that match `"#tst  div"` *at the time the line executes* and calls `draggable()` on those elements. When you add a new element, you need to call `draggable()` on the new element. The previous call doesn't apply.

Comment: Instant feedback wow. Thanks very much for that. Life saver.
I never thought of simply chaining appending and drag. I will remember that advice. Noobs rate up from me. Thanks again.